# Replacing for loop with memcpy in C won't work

Tags: c, memcpy

I should try to make a simple 2-D heat calculation using Jacobi more efficient in C.
After calculating the new array I have to copy the new values into the old array.

At the moment a `for` loop is used:

```c
    for (j = 1; j < sizex - 1; j++) {
                    for (i = 1; i < sizey - 1; i++) {
                            u[j * sizex + i] = utmp[j * sizex + i];
                    }
            }
```

My thought was to use `memcpy` instead, but I think I am doing something wrong:

```c
    memcpy(u, utmp,sizex*sizey*sizeof(unsigned));
```

My results are completely wrong after using `memcpy` instead of the `for` loop.

The whole function:

```
void relax_jacobi(double *u, double *utmp, unsigned sizex, unsigned sizey) {
        int i, j;
        double unew, diff, sum = 0.0;
        for (j = 1; j < sizex - 1; j++) {
                for (i = 1; i < sizey - 1; i++) {
                        utmp[j * sizex + i] = 0.25 * (u[j * sizex + (i - 1)] +
                                                u[j * sizex + (i + 1)] +
                                                u[(j - 1) * sizex + i] +
                                                u[(j + 1) * sizex + i]);
                }
        }

        /*for (j = 1; j < sizex - 1; j++) {
                for (i = 1; i < sizey - 1; i++) {
                        u[j * sizex + i] = utmp[j * sizex + i];
                }
        }*/
        memcpy(u,utmp,sizex*sizex*sizeof(double));
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I never really worked with C before. Is it even the right approach?

The `for` loop starts at 1, as the 2x2 Grid won't change at the edges.

Comment: `for (j = 1; j < sizex - 1; j++)` --> starting at 1 is unusual.  `memcpy()` code is as if starting at 0.

Comment: `sizeof(unsigned)` should be `sizeof(double)`. That may or may not be the only problem.

Comment: Why do you believe you need to "copy the new values into the old array"?  It will almost certainly be better if you do not do that.  If `old` points to the old array, and `new` points to the new array, it would (almost certainly) be better to do `old = new`.

Answer (score 2):

OP's `memcpy(u, utmp,sizex*sizey*sizeof(double));` (which copies all the matrix) is not the same code as below code is copying all but the outer 4 edges of the 2D matrix.

```
for (j = 1; j < sizex - 1; j++) {
  for (i = 1; i < sizey - 1; i++) {
    u[j * sizex + i] = utmp[j * sizex + i];
  }
}
```

is like

```
for (j = 1; j < sizex - 1; j++) {
  // Copy 1 inner sub-row at a time.
  memcpy(&u[j * sizex + 1], &temp[j * sizex + 1], sizeof *u * (sizey-2));
}
```

---

Use `sizeof *u` instead of `sizeof (double)` to avoid coding errors (as OP originally posted).